# Clone certain group of elements from external SVG and use that group to create another SVG

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to use only certain group of elements from external SVG file(icons.svg) and use the selected group to create another SVG tag. The reason for trying to have it this way is that I don't want to have separate SVG file for every single icon as there will be tons of them eventually.

I prefer using D3 and currently my HTML code is following (which doesn't work):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head><script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script></head>
<body>
<script>

d3.xml("icons.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
 if (error) throw error;
 iconSvg = xml.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]; 
 
 sel = d3.select(iconSvg).selectAll("#icon2");
 
 var newSvg = d3.select("body").append("svg")  
        .attr({"id":"newicon", "width":50, "height":50
        }).append(sel);
});

</script>
```

The "icons.svg" file content is following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="100%" version="1.1" id="icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
 <g id="icon1" width="16" height="16" >
  <circle cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="6.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#00AD5A" />
 </g>
 <g id="icon2" width="16" height="16" >
  <circle cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="6.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#FF0000" />
 </g>
 <g id="icon3"  width="16" height="16" >
  <circle cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="6.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#FF00FF" />
 </g> 
</svg>
```

I'd be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution to the problem. I changed lines

```
sel = d3.select(iconSvg).selectAll("#icon2");
```

to this:

```
sel = d3.select(iconSvg).select("#icon2").html();
```

and

```
var newSvg = d3.select("body").append("svg")  
        .attr({"id":"newicon", "width":50, "height":50
        }).append(sel);
```

to this:

```
var newSvg = d3.select("body").append("svg")  
        .attr({"id":"newicon", "width":50, "height":50
        }).append("g").html(sel);
```

and the end result is what I want.